# Pass Fetch API Response to Stack.Screen in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am building an application which has one API call at the start of the application which contains all data for the application. I am then using React Navigation to route to the home screen (and further screens). I am trying to pass the data from the API call to the home screen, but I am not receiving it in my Home element.

The code is as so:

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {

const [responseJson, setResponseJson] = useState([])

async function fetchData() {
  await fetch('http://api.xxx.com/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    setResponseJson(responseJson);
  })
}
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" response={responseJson} component={Home} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

**Home.js**

```
export const Home = (props) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {console.log(props)}
    </View>
  )
}
```

The console.log is providing me an `Object` with `navigation` and `route` keys, but no `response` key. How would I go about passing the data to the Home screen?

Comment: its just not the way it works. The props are not drilled to the screen. you are better of doing the data fetching in the screen itself

Comment: I'm attempting to do just one API call (rather than one on each screen) and pass that information down to the relevant screen

Comment: you can use react context to do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use context. Simply wrap your navigator in a context provider and pass the value down. You should not be passing props to the component through render props or params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useEffect hook from React. But I'm not sure if you get them by passing them to Stack.Screen that way. I think it should be something like this :

```js
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={props => <Home {...props} response={responseJson}/>} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
```

Hook Example:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await fetch('http://api.xxx.com/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setResponseJson(responseJson);
      })
    }
    fetchData()
    // cleanup function if needed, on unmount
    // return () => doSomeCleanUp()
},[])
```

Comment: You are breaking async/await pattern here. You don't need .then : const response = await fetch(...); const json = await response.json(); setResponseJson(json);

Comment: This solution will work but i'm afraid it can be inefficient. the function will be re created and evaluated in each render. It will probably be better to use context here.

Comment: It's not evalueted each render, because the hook evaluets only once when the navigator is mounted.